# firefox does not get elements by name

Tags: javascript, firefox

This piece of code does not seem to work with Firefox, however it works without any problem on Chrome and IE:

```
f = document.forms["form1"];
var nombre = f.elements.item("nombre").value;
var email = f.elements.item("email").value;
var coment = f.elements.item("coment").value;
```

instead of assigning the corresponding value to the variables it just repeats the same value for all the variables so assuming the input `nombre` has the value `john`, `email` and `coment` will also have `john` even though in the input boxes of the form the values are different.

So how to I check the values accordingly?

Comment: show us some code of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like so:

```
var f = document.getElementById( 'form1' );
var nombre = f.elements.namedItem( 'nombre' ).value;
var email = f.elements.namedItem( 'email' ).value;
var coment = f.elements.namedItem( 'coment' ).value;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PQB4q/1/

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem, just out of curiosity why does m first code didn't work on firefox but worked normally on other browsers?

Comment: @HectorDanielZebaduaJerez Firefox doesn't implement the `elements.item( name )` form. In Firefox, you can either do `elements[ name ]` or `elements[ index ]`... Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements

Comment: Per spec, the `item` method takes an integer.  So all your strings were being converted to integers (and in particular to the integer 0).  If you want to get items by name from `form.elements`, use namedItem.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Ah yes. `.namedItem()` instead of `.item()`. However, `.elements.namedItem( name )` is not necessary since `.elements[ name ]` works, too.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas They're not actually equivalent.  For example, `.elements["length"]` will return the length of the list, not an item with the name `length`.  Similar for `.elements["item"]`: that will return a function object, not an element with name `item`.  And if the list has any expandos set on it those would shadow the `[]` form of the access, but not the `namedItem` form.  If you're using a literal string that you know doesn't match any property on the HTMLCollection prototype chain (and never will as specs change!) and know there are no expandos, then you're right that the `[]` form is OK.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Now, that you've laid it out, it occurred to me - the `[]` form is not OK. `.namedItem()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
var nombre = document.getElementById.item.value; //for example
```